# Modal forms dropping # in the address

Tags: javascript

I have made neat comment link for anonymous users http://example.com/modal_forms/nojs/login?destination=http://example.com/comment/reply/NID#comment-form
However when I click it then the `#comment-form` is missing and it's very inconvenient because have to scroll to the comment form, how to fix it?

Here's the code responsible for opening login links in modal window:

`Drupal.behaviors.initModalFormsLogin = function (context) {
  $("a[href*='/user/login'], a[href*='?q=user/login']", context).each(function () {
    this.href = this.href.replace(/user\/login/, 'modal_forms/nojs/login');
  }).addClass('init-modal-forms-login ctools-use-modal ctools-modal-modal-popup-small');
};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you URL encode, the fragment (what you have after the `#` sign) is not sent to the server.

If you want to include the hash in the `destination` parameter, it has to be URL encoded.

> http://example.com/modal_forms/nojs/login?destination=comment/reply/NID%23comment-form

Note the `%23` above. It makes the browser think that the fragment is part of the `destination` parameter.

Comment: Thanks alot! Works like a charm, I'll remember that for the future.